# How to plot density horizontally in plotnine?

Tags: python, density-plot, plotnine

Running the code:

```
from plotnine import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.normal(0,10,1000), 'group': ['a']*500 + ['b']*500})
# 
plot = (
    ggplot(df, aes(x = 'values', y='..density..', fill = 'group'))
    + geom_density(alpha = 0.7)
)

plot
```

Returns the following plot:

[image]

Simply flipping coordinates results in this:

```
plot+coord_flip()
```

[image]

What needs to be done so that the second plot looks right?

Comment: This is a bug and it has been fixed. Next release which will contain the fix will be out within a week.

Comment: @has2k1 I also posted this an issue to the Issue Tracker, because I couldn't implement this fix myself to make a PR :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/596) was corrected in `plotnine` [696a3bb](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/696a3bbf3e4c25554c9939063d370a9562dd3275), and so the code to run remains the same